# Scrolling very bugging on mobile with custom dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I used the [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp) for the following code. I need a dropdown that has a search bar. I got it how I want it but scrolling on mobile is super weird and buggy. **Sometimes you can scroll and sometimes you are stuck in the middle of the big list on mobile only, desktop scrolls fine.**

Anyone that has a tip on how to fix this?

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-top: 1px solid #575757;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 4.5;
  color: #D6C196;
  text-indent: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Selecteer een categorie &#x25BC;</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Zoeken" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
      <a href="www.google.nl">Google</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</div>
```

Kind regards,
Pieter

Comment: Try giving your dropdown-content a fixed height then `overflow-y:scroll;`

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa This indeed fixes the wierd scrolly bit but now the content does not push down when opening the dropdown making so you don't see the whole dropdown bit. Meaning that you have to scroll down in an awkward way to fully display all the content of the dropdown. If that makes sense.

Comment: Everydrop down control out there, the user scroll through it's content, i don't see what you're trying to do

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa When I open the dropdown the content drops out of frame. When I did not add overflow-y:scroll and fixed height, the content dragged the screen down a bit showing more option.

Comment: That's why i suggested you add a fixed height to it with overflow-y:scroll

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Yes and now when I add that, the dropdown does not push the content down and also does not push the screen down to somewhat fit the dropdown. Making it so I have to scroll down manually to see the full dropdown, And this scrolling is once again quite buggy.

Comment: So you want the dropdown to fill the height, and then enable the scrolling ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I want the dropdown to push the screen down so no further scrolling is required to get a decent view on the dropdown. Now half of the fixed height dropdown is off the screen.

Comment: You can't push the screen down, that would be scaling the whole document out, So everything will end up small, if you have a preview of what you're trying to achieve, please do show.